# What should I name my variables in a translation project?

Tags: localization, yaml, translation, abstraction

I'm abstracting strings from views and I don't want to name my variables after the strings... what should I name them? I also don't want to number them in case I insert a new string into a view at some point.

I want short names that are easy to reference, not hard to put into my brain's short term memory, and not confusing to my translators.

The current version is in English, the future versions will be in Chinese, Spanish, Vietnamese, and Tagalog, in addition to English.

Comment: What about naming them for their roles? E.g. the string that holds the value "hello" in the English translation could be called `greeting_string`? At some point, it may be easiest to do exactly what you said you don't want to do in the beginning - name them after the strings themselves. I agree with you that numbering them is not a good approach.

Comment: I think you are right, I should name them after the strings themselves. For instance, we use the word "now" all by itself over and over. We should only translate it once. ...right?

Comment: also I'm going to clarify the title of the questions a little.

Comment: This looks interesting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Localization_content_best_practices

Comment: good reading -- thank you!
long descriptive variable names + very precise notes

Comment: Who takes the time to down-vote questions? So mean. StackOverflow should remove that feature.

Answer (score 2):

**long descriptive names** that are similar to the original string.

Based on this Mozilla article 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Localization_content_best_practices

Thanks to @davejagoda for the advice.